# How to flush the value of StringBuilder variable in android?

Tags: android, stringbuilder

I am working on an android app in which i have a static StringBuilder variable named DT_selected.I want to flush this variable's value on a checkbox check.Anyone have any idea or experience how to do it?

Comment: Matthew is correct. The StringBuilder class is meant to be temporary to build a single String then go away. The solution is therefore to replace the contents of the variable with a brand new clean shiny reference. i.e. builder = new StringBuilder();

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking to do but you can't "flush" a string builder, its not a stream. You can get its contents with `toString()` or you can create a new empty string builder:

```
 builder = new StringBuilder();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
i have used...

someStringBuilder.Remove(0,someStringBuilder.Length);

or
string theString = someStringBuilder.ToString();
someStringBuilder.Replace(theString,"");

 it will help u...
```

Comment: myStringBuilder.setLength(0);
or this myStringBuilder.delete(0, myStringBuilder.length());
try it

Comment: Found no such method "Remove" or "remove" on StringBuilder variable.And my app is crashing while using "replace" method.So waiting for another solution.

Comment: himanshu u try this...myStringBuilder.setLength(0); or this myStringBuilder.delete(0, myStringBuilder.length()); ??????

Comment: dear i had used from thses of one methos in past it was working

Comment: Jigar, there are no such methods as these. Perhaps you were using a different class or an extended StringBuilder, but neither your answer nor comments apply to the standard StringBuilder that himanshu is using. Of course, a solution is always to extend the StringBuilder. *wink wink*